# Multithreaded server in java.. Threads serving files

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

So I am writing a multithreaded server which takes in as an input the server name, port, number of threads, and a file name to request.. My design is to create a socket through main and then extend a Runnable object (which takes in a socket and the file name).. I also have a timertask which fires when 5 seconds are over and then closes and stops all threads.. My current design is to create the socket in main, pass it to runnable (where there is a while loop on condition x, requesting the file over and over), and then when the task fires up it sets the private shared variable x in runnable to false.

I am facing a lot of broken pipe issues which leads me to believe my design is flawed.. Am I missing something? I am not using synchronized/locked variables. Should I create a new socket for every file request?

Stacktrace:

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeBytes(DataOutputStream.java:259)
    at FR.filesRecv(Client.java:62)
    at FR.run(Client.java:79)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

Comment: It's a little bit confusing what is server side and what is client-side.  Can you edit your question and make this more clear?

Comment: Also, what sort of 'broken pipe issues' are you having.  An exception with some of the stacktrace lines is *always* a good idea to put at the end of your question.

Comment: So the client is writing bytes to the server?  If the pipe is broken then it looks like the server has closed the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general comments:

- Yes, each client should have their own socket connection to the server.
- On the server side, there is a server socket but when a connection is accepted from a client, a new socket is created for each handler to talk to its corresponding client.
- I would fork the threads in `main` and then just sleep for 5 seconds and then set the `runnable` variables to be false.  No need for the timer-task.
- You can then either exit immediately from `main` if you want the JVM to stop quickly or you can call `join()` on each of your threads to make sure they finish appropriately.  You can also set `thread.setDaemon(false);` before the thread starts and then exit `main` and the JVM won't stop until the threads finish on their own.
- You need to make sure that the `runnable` variable is `volatile` if it is going to be set from another thread.

Comment: Gray: I still get broken pipe (I call Thread.sleep(5*1000L) in my main thread after starting the threads).. I am spawning off only one thread for debugging purposes and it only gets the first file then complains about broken pipe. Do I need a new socket connection every writeBytes or can I reuse the socket? Updated the question with the stacktrace.

Comment: Can you address my comments to your question.  "It's a little bit confusing what is server side and what is client-side. Can you edit your question and make this more clear?"  You mention that your command line client creates a server that requests a file.  That sounds like a client.  I can't picture what you are trying to do.